# Sapui5 Back Button on Android Device

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, sapui5

I have a sapui5 mobile application which runs perfectly. The android device has a back button. What I want to achieve is that when you press the button the app should navigate back.
In the sapui5 mobile api it is possible with this coding:

```
app.back();
```

The question now is how I can make this?
The activity of my android application has the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //Here you should navigate one view back
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is it possible to call from my activity the app variable in javascript and then tell my application to navigate back?

Greetings
Stef

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. On the one hand you are talking about UI5 and on the other hand (as it looks to me) about android development. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you using a WebView to display a UI5 page and want to execute javascript code inside that view?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for solving the problem ... I wrote a new javascript file with the following code:

```
function onBackKeyDown(){
     // Handle here the BackButton
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function init(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

I took this out of the phonegap api and works perfectly!

Greetings

Stef

Comment: It will be applicable for the all pages of you application. Not a gud solution.